# Control not getting added in Win32 LPDLGTEMPLATE

Tags: windows, winapi

In my Win32 application, I register a custom class with the name "AX."

The following dialog resource, as defined in an .rc file, works as expected:

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 457, 219
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    CONTROL "{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}", IDC_EXPLORER1, "AX", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 500, 400
END
```

However, in my case, I cannot use any .rc file. Basically, I would need to build DLGTEMPLATE in memory and call DialogBoxIndirect. Here is my relevant code:

```
lpdt->style = DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU /*| DS_NOFAILCREATE*/;
lpdt->cdit = 1;         // Number of controls
lpdt->x = 10;  lpdt->y = 10;
lpdt->cx = 500; lpdt->cy = 400;

LPWORD lpw = (LPWORD)(lpdt + 1);
*lpw++ = 0;             // No menu
*lpw++ = 0;             // Predefined dialog box class (by default)

LPWSTR lpwsz = (LPWSTR)lpw;
int nchar = 1 + MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "My Dialog", -1, lpwsz, 50);
lpw += nchar;

////-----------------------
//// Define the WebBrowser Control.
////-----------------------
lpw = lpwAlign(lpw); 
LPDLGITEMTEMPLATE lpdit = (LPDLGITEMTEMPLATE)lpw;
lpdit->x  = 0; lpdit->y  = 0;
lpdit->cx = 300; lpdit->cy = 300;
lpdit->id = IDC_EXPLORER1; 
lpdit->style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE;

// Class for the activeXControl
lpw = (LPWORD)(lpdit + 1);
*lpw++ = 0xFFFF;
*lpw++ = atom; // Here, atom was obtained from RegisterClassEx() for class name "AX"

lpw = (LPWORD) (lpdit + 1);
lpwsz = (LPWSTR) lpw;
nchar = 1 + MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, "{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}", -1, lpwsz, 2048); 
lpw   += nchar;
*lpw++ = 0; // no creation data

GlobalUnlock(hgbl);
LRESULT ret = DialogBoxIndirect(hinst, (LPDLGTEMPLATE)hgbl, hwndOwner, DialogProc);
GlobalFree(hgbl);

if (ret == -1) {
    int err = ::GetLastError();
    ReportError(err);
}
```

The return code from DialogBoxIndirect is -1. However, GetLastError() returns 0. Strange.

If I specify DS_NOFAILCREATE in the dialog box style, the dialog box does get created. However, the control I need is missing.

Please help me identify the problem in my code. Regards.

Comment: Have you initialised COM correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your error might be here:

```
// Class for the activeXControl
lpw = (LPWORD)(lpdit + 1);
*lpw++ = 0xFFFF;
*lpw++ = atom; // Here, atom was obtained from RegisterClassEx() for class name "AX"

lpw = (LPWORD) (lpdit + 1);   // <--- ERROR HERE
lpwsz = (LPWSTR) lpw;
```

You're reassigning `lpw` to `lpdit + 1` again, which means you write your control title text over the class atom. Looks like a bad copy + paste job.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you for your help. I commented out the line. However, the problem still does not go away.

Answer (score 0):

Let the compiler create the dialog template. Just use a binary editor and just copy the sequence and define it as a char array, or whatever.

That's the way I do it and it avoids mistakes.